# Trying to edit a post when not logged in gives pending edit warning

Tags: bug, edits

When not logged in any attempt to navigate to a Meta Stack Overflow edit page will result in a pending suggested edit error:

> There is a pending suggested edit in the queue. Try again in a few minutes.

this occurs even though it's not possible to suggest edits on MSO:

[image: Screenshot showing issue on Meta Stack Overflow]

Test link (remember to log out or use a browser you're not logged in with): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/399167/edit

The same response is returned when trying to edit an SO main question which is less than 10 minutes old (i.e., trying to edit a post before the *"improve this question"* button has appeared).

Should this not instead redirect users to the log in page or give an appropriate warning.

Comment: Duplicate on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138879/navigating-to-the-edit-mode-of-a-not-exist-page-produces-a-strange-error-message (and also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261022/wrong-error-message-when-suggesting-an-edit-on-a-per-site-meta-when-not-logged-i)